# Mysql Update y insert en un solo query

Tags: mysql, sql

como puedo escribir un Query que haga un update de ciertos campos donde lo único que quiero comprobar es el IDKey, pero si no encuentra el IDKey, no existe el registro, haga un Insert del registro usando esta misma informacion

lo que tengo:

```
str="UPDATE Det_Info SET Size=1, Color=1 WHERE KeyProduc='0100';
OR
INSERT INTO Det_Info(KeyProduc,Size,Color) VALUES ('0100',1,1);"
```

la idea es que se haga en un solo query, y no esperar la resolución de un query para hacer otro, y la prioridad es hacer el Update. sin procedimientos almacenados.

Comment: Utiliza transaction investigalo un poco y puedes hacer basicamente Update, Insert, delete dentro de la transaccion.

Comment: Has intentado utilizar Store Procedures , checa esta solución , saludos https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957788/insert-and-update-with-stored-procedure

Comment: Has dos consultas Seguidas, la primera después le das executeQuery, en seguida la segunda.

Comment: En esta respuesta de SO en inglés está resuelta tu consulta https://stackoverflow.com/a/4205207/3683321

Answer (score 1):

Haces un insert,y agregas la condición de si encontraste un valor duplicado, esto claro tomando en cuenta que tu columna `KeyProduc` es única, lo cual debería de serlo

```
INSERT INTO Det_Info (KeyProduc,Size,Color) VALUES ('0100', 3,2)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Size = 1, Color = 1;
```

Comment: la prioridad es hacer el update, no el insert.

Comment: Es la única opción que pude encontrar, porque algo como `IF EXISTS ... THEN... ELSE...` no funciona en MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Deberías utilizar un `SELECT` para comprobar si existe el `KeyProduc`

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT COUNT(KeyProduc) FROM Det_Info WHERE KeyProduc='0100';
```

Si el resultado de ese conteo es cero, realizas el `INSERT`; de lo contrario, ejecutas el `UPDATE`.

Comment: la idea es que se haga en un solo query, y no esperar la resolución de un query para hacer otro.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez yo la verdad conozco mas de SQL Server; pero, ¿en MySQL puede hacer un procedimiento almacenado que cumpla con este requerimiento?

Comment: creo que si pero imagínate que por cada tabla tenga que hacer un procedimiento almacenado ..

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez, eso no lo ví en tu pregunta. Creo que si ese es tu verdadero objetivo, deberías editar tu pregunta. Suerte